# Understanding *2.01 of Principia Mathematica

Tags: logic, math-history

I wanted to read Whitehead and Russells Principia Mathematica. I think that I am beginning to get the hang of the notation but I seen to be stuck on the proof of *2.01. They prove that $\vdash : p \supset \sim p \cdot \supset \cdot \sim p $. I understand line 1 of the proof but I cant see the reason for the second line. I will try to reporduce the proof here.
\begin{align*}
\left[ \text{Taut} \frac{\sim p}{p} \right] &\vdash:\sim p \vee \sim p . \supset . \sim p  \\
\left[ \text{(1).(*1.01)}\right ] &\vdash: p \supset \sim p . \supset . \sim p
\end{align*}

From my understanding, the bracket represents the references that justifies the assertion. However, *1.01 is just the definition of implication $\sim p \vee q$. How did they go from $(\sim p \lor \sim p)$ to $(p \supset \sim p)$? Wouldn't that require double negation which hasn't been proven yet?

Comment: Quick question. Why?

Comment: (1)(*1.01) is the justification for replacing "$\sim p \vee \sim p$" with "$p \supset \sim p$", which is just application of the definition of implication specialized to $q \mapsto \sim p$,

Comment: (1) is the first line of the derivation and the formula is obtained from $\text {Taut}$ axiom (1.2, page 96): $⊢ (p∨p) \supset p$, replacing $¬p$ in place of $p$. The second line is obtained from line (1) using Def.1.01 (page 94): $p \supset q = \lnot p \lor q$.

Comment: If we apply Def.1.01 to $\lnot p \lor \lnot p$ what we get is exactly: $p \supset \lnot p$.